# Can't start eclipse

Tags: eclipse

It seems that no questions in this site is the same with mine.

The Eclipse splash window shows up but no progress bar at the bottom of it. I wait a long time but it just hang up there. I've tried to download the Eclipse tarball from Eclipse official website, it doesn't work either.

How can I debug this issue? Thanks.

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.class.path=/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-debug
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.class.path=/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
Install location:
    file:/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.1.v20120830-144521.jar
Splash location:
    /home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/home/ftao/downloads/software/eclipse/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 4
Starting application: 1679
```

Comment: Have you tried starting Eclipse from the terminal?

Comment: @daslinkard, yes, that's what I did. Nothing visible from stdout/stderr of the terminal. So I feel hard to figure out what's going wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step I always take is to start the program in a Terminal window and read the messages that crop up there.  If you don't see anything other than `Segmentation fault` or something equally terse then see if the program has a debug or verbose flag; the man page often has these flags listed.

For Eclipse, I believe the relevant option is `-debug`.  Please double check this though; I'm not 100% sure.  Post any output you get so we can help!

Comment: Thanks. With "-debug" option, I can get more info from the terminal. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: From what I can see in the output, there is no error explicitly printed.  It *does* looks like it just sits there!  Check your CPU and other resource usage (like RAM and HDD access).  Are any of these pegged?  If so, be patient.

Comment: No abnormal hardware resource usage changes. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-clean` option ?

I met the same trouble today, recovered.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me. Still hang~ :\