# cant launch eclipse in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gtk, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unsatisfied Link Error and missing .so files when starting Eclipse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125150/unsatisfied-link-error-and-missing-so-files-when-starting-eclipse)

I am getting a message which says to refer log in .eclipse in home directory  here is the contain of the log(Stack trace)....

```
!SESSION 2013-01-07 13:03:32.749 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-01-07 13:03:33.673
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
    no swt-gtk in java.library.path
    Can't load library: /home/abs/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk-3740.so
    Can't load library: /home/abs/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: We have a bunch of '[Eclipse](http://askubuntu.com/q/207471/12864) [won't](http://askubuntu.com/q/161536/12864) [start](http://askubuntu.com/q/199700/12864)' questions, can you look at those three and see if they help? Yours is very likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with path, try correcting the path to

`ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/`

You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries)

As per the error message `Can't load library: /home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so`

looks like the libraries should be at `.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/` if there are not there you can try this command:

`locate  libswt-gtk.so`

this should find the libraries, copy the entire directory to

`/home/tom/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64`